# Programatically erasing a row in SQL within a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a relational database connecting `meal_ingredients` and `ingredient` nutritional values (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287785/proper-form-in-relational-meal-database) for further information), utilising PostgreSQL. Within a WinForms application, there is a button that takes values from a DataGridView and then places each row into an array.

Each row in the DataGridView is an ingredient with its nutritional values. Above the DataGridView, a textbox takes a string for the meal name. Upon clicking the button (code below), the array values do one of two things:

- If the meal name (`meal_name` being the PK) already exists in the `meal_ingredients` table, all rows in the database containing this string are removed. The rows from the DataGridView are then inserted, effectively 'overwriting' the ingredients for that meal.
- If the meal name does not exist in the `meal_ingredients` table, the rows plus the meal name, entered into the textbox, are simply appended to the table.

In my code, as you can see once the data is placed into the array, a connection is made with the database, and the results from the `SELECT` query loaded into a DataTable.

The loop which follows triggers a MessageBox if the `meal_name` field matches the string value in the textbox. This works fine.

My issue is as follows. For however many rows exist in the DataGridView, the MessageBox will fire off that many times; so with two rows, I will see two MessageBoxes, for example. This, *per se*, is not a problem, unless replacing this MessageBox with `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements would throw an error.

In place of `MessageBox.Show("test");`, I would instead place a SQL statement to remove any records where `meal_name == txtMealName.Text` and then a second SQL statement to insert new records based upon the DataGridView rows. Of course, if the MessageBox fires off according to the number of rows, I expect the SQL would also occur that many times. Again, this is fine in principle. But I am just wondering if this would cause a conflict of any kind (that is, for example, the SQL throwing an exception because there are no remaining rows to delete)?

```
 private void btnMealAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtMealName.Text != "")
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMealIngredient.Rows)
            {
                List<string> macroList = new List<string>();
                macroList.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                macroList.Add(row.Cells[9].Value.ToString());

                macroList.Add(txtMealName.Text);

                String[] str = macroList.ToArray();

                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Globals.connectionString());
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM meal_ingredients";
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);

                foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dataRow[0].ToString() == txtMealName.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("test");
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(dataRow[0]);
                }                    
            }         
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error: enter a meal name");
        }
        
    }
```

A simplified form of the database relation (note that qty is one of the fields in the DataGridView):

[image: db relational image]

Comment: You don't need to select anything to implement your logic; just issue a delete followed by an insert will be fine - the delete will delete 0 or more rows without error(you don't need to check a row exists before attempting a delete). As for why your MessageBox comes multiple times.. well, you *have* shown it within a loop..

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. The intention behind the initial `SELECT` is to capture the data so the DataReader can be compared to Controls in the app. Or have I missed something? To clarify, I have no issue regarding the MessageBox appearing multiple times, just whether replacing that with `INSERT` or `DELETE` will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just whether replacing that with INSERT or DELETE will throw an error

An SQL DELETE can be typically run multiple times without error. There either will be some rows for it to delete or there will not but it will only normally result an error if there are dependent records in another table and no arrangement for them to be deleted or disconnected in cascade fashion. It is not an error for a DELETE statement to affect 0 rows

An SQL INSERT can typically only be run multiple times when it is not subsequently(after the first run) inhibited by the presence of a unique constraint on one or more of the columns. As most tables you design should really have a primary key, you can only insert a row with a unique value for the key column. If you aren't devolving generation of the value to the database then re-running an identical INSERT will fail on the second run. If the table depends on another table to have a related row and a foreign key constraint backs this up, then an insert that doesn't relate to a row in the parent table will fail on first run

Comment: Thanks, that answers the query.